# Retrieve the latest comment from a github issue

Tags: go, github-api

I am wondering what would be the most efficient way to retrieve the latest comment from a github issue using Go.

I actually know how to do this already but I am not satisfied with the performance so I would love to get some suggestions

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    owner, repo := "owner", "repo"

    token := oauth2.Token{AccessToken: os.Getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")}
    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&token)

    ctx := context.Background()
    tc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)
    gc := github.NewClient(tc)
    gc.BaseURL, _ = url.Parse("https://api.github.com/")

    opts := github.IssueListByRepoOptions{}
    issues, _, _ := gc.Issues.ListByRepo(ctx, owner, repo, &opts)


    // Implement Here: get latest comment for issues[0]

    return
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why not include the code you're already using, or at least a summary of it?

Comment: The code I am using is complicated but I'll try to come up with something shorter

Comment: When saying you are not satisfied with performance, I would request two things: some kind of indication of what performance you are getting, and also, some kind of attempt to analyze where the performance is not good.  Without either one, attempting to "fix" the performance might be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rest API v3 or GraphQL v4. If you plan to loop through a lot of issues, graphQL definitly worth it

#### Using Rest API v3

Using [go-github](https://github.com/google/go-github) as you suggested, you can use :

```
ListComments(ctx context.Context, owner string, repo string, number int, opts *IssueListCommentsOptions)
```

For example from [this test](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/1ceaa95a5d70f22e95f3212dec0c346d38591d73/github/issues_comments_test.go#L35-L44)

For example to get the last comment for the last 20 opened issues (from your code).

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    owner, repo := "google", "gson"

    token := oauth2.Token{AccessToken: os.Getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")}
    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&token)

    ctx := context.Background()
    tc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)
    gc := github.NewClient(tc)
    gc.BaseURL, _ = url.Parse("https://api.github.com/")

    opts := github.IssueListByRepoOptions{}
    issues, _, _ := gc.Issues.ListByRepo(ctx, owner, repo, &opts)

    for i := 0; i < len(issues); i++ {
        opt := &github.IssueListCommentsOptions{}
        comments, _, err := gc.Issues.ListComments(ctx, owner, repo, *issues[i].Number, opt)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        } else if len(comments) > 0 {
            log.Println(*comments[0].Body)
        } else {
            log.Println("no comment for this issue")
        }
    }
}
```

It will perform :

- one request to get the last 20 opened issues
- one request for each issue to get the last comments

So a total of 21 requests

#### Using GraphQL v4

You can use [githubv4 library](https://github.com/shurcooL/githubv4) to use [Github GraphQL v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/).

The same as previous example in GraphQL would be :

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/shurcooL/githubv4"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    owner, repo := "google", "gson"

    token := oauth2.Token{AccessToken: os.Getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")}
    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&token)

    httpClient := oauth2.NewClient(context.Background(), ts)
    client := githubv4.NewClient(httpClient)
    {
        var q struct {
            Repository struct {
                Issues struct {
                    Nodes []struct {
                        Number int
                        Comments struct {
                            Nodes []struct {
                                Body   githubv4.String
                            }
                        } `graphql:"comments(last:$commentsLast)"`
                    }
                    PageInfo struct {
                        EndCursor   githubv4.String
                        HasNextPage githubv4.Boolean
                    }
                } `graphql:"issues(last:$issuesLast,states:OPEN)"`
            } `graphql:"repository(owner:$repositoryOwner,name:$repositoryName)"`
        }
        variables := map[string]interface{}{
            "repositoryOwner": githubv4.String(owner),
            "repositoryName":  githubv4.String(repo),
            "issuesLast": githubv4.NewInt(20),
            "commentsLast": githubv4.NewInt(1),
        }
        err := client.Query(context.Background(), &q, variables)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        printJSON(q)
    }
}

func printJSON(v interface{}) {
    w := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    w.SetIndent("", "\t")
    err := w.Encode(v)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This is modification of [the example](https://github.com/shurcooL/githubv4/blob/master/example/githubv4dev/main.go) from the github repo

The code above will perform exactly 1 request